# Using a deleted scope with Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden, soft-delete

I'm using Devise to handle authentication in a Rails app, and I'm using permanent_records to soft delete users. The default scope for my User model is the undeleted users. If a user deletes (deactivates) his account, I want him to be able to reactivate his account by logging in, similar to the way Facebook does it. Problem is, since Devise doesn't know to look for deleted users, no account is found. I thought about overriding the sessions#create method

```
 def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

But since this is handled by Warden, it seems I'm out of luck. I'm afraid that if I start digging too deep I'm going to start breaking things.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

1. Overwrite `find_for_authentication` method in User model to allow finding for any users https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L229
2. Redefine `after_database_authentication` method in your model to remove deleted flag here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L98

That is all, I believe. No need to touch controller actions.

Comment: Awesome! So if I'm overriding find_for_authentication, how do I tell it not to use the default scope? Their example is find_first_by_auth_conditions(tainted_conditions, :active => true), but I don't want :deleted => true, I want both deleted AND undeleted records so that I can apply some special logic to deleted records.

Comment: More specifically, it would be awesome if I could do something like user = super || find_first_by_auth_conditions(tainted_conditions, :deleted_at => "IS NOT NULL") but of course "IS NOT NULL" is not something I can pass to the hash. How can I find records where deleted_at is present?

Comment: You can write own finder here (because you know your adapter and fields) `unscoped.where(tainted_conditions).first`

Comment: Brilliant. You sir, are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

this works with the paranoia gem:

```
class << self
  def find_for_authentication(conditions)
    User.unscoped do
      user = super(conditions)
      user.restore!(recursive: true) if user.deleted?
      user
    end
  end
end
```